# The "dryRun" flag means no changes were made

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, vscode-devcontainer, nomachine-nx

When I try to create a component via Nx console in Angular it shows like below:

NX  Generating @nrwl/angular:component

```
CREATE src/app/parameterpage/parameterpage.component.css
CREATE src/app/parameterpage/parameterpage.component.html
CREATE src/app/parameterpage/parameterpage.component.spec.ts
CREATE src/app/parameterpage/parameterpage.component.ts
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts
```

NOTE: The "dryRun" flag means no changes were made.

I tried to run with --dry, but nothing happend